# Quarkus native binary (Graavlvm) incompatible

Tags: java, quarkus, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to create an Azure module client using a native binary ?

(I tried Quarkus and couldn't get it working with native binary, but it worked with JVM.)

I got stuck with the following stacktrace:

```
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304627ZCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load platform constants for ProtocolFamily
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304636Z at jnr.constants.platform.ConstantResolver.getConstants(ConstantResolver.java:227)
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304644Z at jnr.constants.platform.ConstantResolver.lookupAndCacheConstant(ConstantResolver.java:128)
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304651Z at jnr.constants.platform.ConstantResolver.getConstant(ConstantResolver.java:116)
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304676Z at jnr.constants.platform.ConstantResolver.longValue(ConstantResolver.java:179)
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304684Z at jnr.constants.platform.ProtocolFamily.intValue(ProtocolFamily.java:48)
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304691Z at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix.setFamily(SockAddrUnix.java:55)
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304699Z at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketAddress.<init>(UnixSocketAddress.java:48)
2021-10-06T23:05:27.304733Z at com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.hsm.HttpsHsmClient.sendHttpRequestUsingUnixSocket.connect(HttpsHsmClient.java:238)


pom dependencies

pom dependencies

<quarkus.platform.version>2.2.2.Final</quarkus.platform.version>

<dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
      <artifactId>iot-device-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.21.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please add relevant dependencies from pom causing this.

Comment: Native compilation has some hidden magic and not all libraries are compatible specially if they use reflection. I think that the main issue that you are facing is with graal vm, have you checked if you library has some issues with graalvm?

Comment: Yes so if the application uses reflection then it has to be registered beforehand otherwise it won't be able to find it during runtime. But which is the class here is what we should look at. And to answer your questions these all libs that microsft azure provides does not have native graalvm support and we shud probably raise a pr with them.